# Как объединить две таблицы в одну?

Tags: mysql, sql

Как в запросе объединить две таблички (один столбец) в одну и получить два столбца?

Comment: В каждой таблице только один столбец? Вам нужно менять структуру базы данных.

Comment: @MrClon, смелый совет.

Comment: Может я чего-то не понимаю, но насколько мне известно таблица из одного столбца это неправильное использование РСУБД

Comment: @MrClon справочник натуральных ключей, например, или список забаненных айпи.

Comment: Я не говорю что это ненужно, я говорю что это нереляционно (отношений-то нет). А @sitev_ru, видимо, хочет производить над этой таблицей какие-то реляционные операции.

Comment: @sitev_ru, может опишите подробнее что там у вас? Есть подозрение что вы что-то делаете не так.

Answer (score 2):

[SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) с указанием названий нужных таблиц, [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) или же [Представления](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)

Comment: не покажите на примере?

Comment: Вообще-то, join и union объединят две таблицы в один столбец, а не два. Нужно знать какое отношение между двумя таблицами. Например, если в них разное количество строк, что тогда выводить?

Comment: Если разное кол-во строк - выводить там где больше

Comment: @sitev_ru, вы ссылки открывали? там есть примеры
@cadmy, а если мы не знаем, какое отношение между таблицами, то по какой логике их вообще обьединять?

Answer (score 1):

Допустим если есть 2 таблицы с полями `idX, valueX` со связкой через поля `idX`, тогда пишем так:

```
select t1.value1, t2.value2 
  from table1 as t1 
  inner join table2 as t2 on t1.id1=t2.id2
```

Ну и с вариациями `left/right join`

Answer (score 1):

Как понял:

```
/*
create table t1(a int);
create table t2 (b char);
insert into t1 values (1),(2),(3);
insert into t2 values ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d');
*/
set @x =0, @y =0;
select a,b from (
select *, @x:=@x+1 as x from t1) t1
right join (
select *, @y:=@y+1 as y from t2) t2
on x=y;
```